# React: Access to fetch at URL has been blocked by CORS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors

I am trying to fetch an API endpoint in React. It works fine in my localhost environment but when I build the React project and upload the build files to Firebase Hosting I get this error on my now publicly hosted URL:

`Access to fetch at 'API URL' from origin 'WEBSITE URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to whitelist the origin (where the request is coming from) in your Firebase app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know where I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution:**

I was unable to figure out the CORS related issue on the client side so I ended up migrating my API `fetch()` calls to my backend.

I was able to use [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own backend i think it's because you not specified allowed link to access your backend,

this work on me:

```
app.use(require("cors")({
  origin: "your website link"
  })
);
```